# Easiest way to convert string to int array

Tags: c++, c

What is an easy way to convert a string

"1 0 2 1 4 5 6 195"

to an int array (or a vector)? I am aware of the possible solutions but they all seem too complicated for my purposes (string is formatted as given in example). std::string or char[] are both ok.

Comment: C *or* C++? They are different languages/environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

// get string
std::string input = "1 0 2 1 4 5 6 195";

// convert to a stream
std::stringstream in( input);

// convert to vector of ints
std::vector<int> ints;
std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int, char>(in),
                std::istream_iterator<int, char>(), std::back_inserter( ints ) );
```